# What is the best method for optimizing runtime of kd-tree in Python?

Tags: python, scipy, kdtree

I'm currently using Python's scipy.spatial.kdtree to perform nearest neighbor lookups between two large sets of earth science data. One is a collection of storm reports that have a specific lat/lon attached; the other is 1x1 km gridded data containing land use data for half of the United States.

I've performed kd-tree operations on similar datasets which had roughly 4.4 * 10 ^ 7 points to sort in the kd-tree and that successfully sorted in approximately 160 seconds; however, when I try to build a kd-tree with this dataset (has approximately 1.6 * 10 ^ 8 points to sort), my kernel simply times out. I'm aware that a kd-tree runs at Olog(n) runtime, though I'm not too familiar with the finer workings of big-O notation, so I'm unsure as to whether or not this should cause an exponential increase in runtime.

Is this likely due to machine timeouts that could be optimized through better data partitioning prior to building the kd-tree, or does this seem to be somewhat of a fluke?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "my kernel simply times out." what does that mean, exactly?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm running the script through JupyterLab with a remote desktop connection. As I'm running the script, the kernel will simply stop execution of the cell while building the tree. It's possible that the timeout is due to intermittent disconnections from the server, or that it results from an overload of processing due to the immense size of the tree.

Comment: Please try to make the question more focused. At the moment your background description is clear, but the question is a bit too open to be easily answered. Suggestion to refined questions: "How can I analyze if the method fails due to too large data set?" or "How do I diagnose a non-responsive kernel in jupyter lab?"

Comment: If the first question is applicable: take a random subset of N datapoints from the data and run your algorithm. Record the runtime and memory utilization. Then increase N and see if you get some thresholding effect. Does the runtime increase slowly (then its the log(n) behavior that is too bad and you need to parallellize i guess....) or with a bump (out-of-memory issues, paging etc).

Answer (score 1):

Can you put your data on a regular grid, 1 km squares with high values over oceans ? Then
[scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.html)
is *waaay* faster than KDTree -- there's no "build tree" at all.
(The lower 48 states run from latitudes about 25 to 49 degrees,
longitudes -125 to -67, so less than 17 million 1 km squares -- should fit, use np.float32.)

Also you could try `KDtree( data, leafsize=100 )`: faster build tree, slower queries.
How many query points, storm reports, are there ?